# Do transactions lock the tables updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

Do sql transactions lock the tables updated in the transaction?

For example;

Several programs want to access a Foo table which keeps a counter value. I d like to change the counter value in the transaction and if it the trans. fails in the subsequent steps then the transaction roll backs and the counter value remains the same(the old value).
During the transaction, Do the other programs gain access the Foo table?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 RC

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: Is your concern that you want to maintain a counter in a table, or is it a more general question about locking ?

Comment: what i d like to manage is espacially the counter in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the subject of maintaining counters I would recommend you investigate 'Autoincrement' because this solves the problem you are addressing.

The limitation is that you cannot guarantee there are no gaps in the sequence.  This is because of the answer to your second question.

If transaction 'A' begins with a new counter value, Tran 'B' can follow with another before 'A' has committed - so yes - the table is accessible.

If you try and manage counters yourself (perhaps to try and avoid gaps) you will have to cope with the possibility that tran 'C' comes along after 'A' has rolled back but before 'B' has committed - and you will have a duplicate.  Using the AutoIncrement mechanism will guard against that, but the counter will have a gap left by Tran 'A'.

Hopefully that is the issue you are tackling.

Comment: @Bill - does that answer your query ?

Comment: Yes @Hugh,your answer was very helpful for me. Thank you very much